# Extracting last IPv4 octet value for each host in Ansible without extra debug info

Tags: ansible, ipv4

I'm trying to get the 4th IPv4 octet for each host in Ansible. 
However, I only get it with extra debug info. 
I would like to get only the value. 
An example  IP of one host: 172.27.0.4 
Current output for example:

```
{"msg": "4", "failed": false, "changed": false}
```

The output I would like to get is:

```
4
```

My current playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: print 4th octet
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ ip.split('.')[3] }}"
      register: ip1
    - name: write 4th octet to file
      copy: content="{{ ip1 }}" dest=/root/ip.txt
```

The output is written to file to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this in a single task.
*The debug task is not necessary, as well as the definition of the varaiable `ip`.*

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: write 4th octet to file
      copy: content="{{ (ansible_default_ipv4.address | split('.')).3 }}" dest=/root/ip.txt
```

For clarity, you can define a varaiable within the task that is only valid during task execution.
*I would prefer this variant.*

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: write 4th octet to file
      copy:
        dest: /root/ip.txt
        content: "{{ ip }}"
      vars:
        ip: "{{ (ansible_default_ipv4.address | split('.')).3 }}"
```

---

- What you are doing at the moment is the whole thing in three steps:

  1. Define variable `ip` and store the value of another variable in it.
  2. perform an operation and output it (via `debug`), at the same time register the output
  3. use the value registered by the output to write it to a file

     This can be summarized as described above.
- The output you mention is that of the `debug` task.

  ```
  {"msg": "4", "failed": false, "changed": false}
  ```

  Since you registered the output in the variable `ip1`, you could access the actual output value via `ip1.msg`. But this is not necessary, because for your case the `debug` task is not needed at this point.

---

#### more detailed description for accessing the default IP address

You use `hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']` to access the IP address, more precisely the variable `ansible_default_ipv4` of the current host, because the variable `inventory_hostname` returns you the host of the system on which the play is currently running. You can access this variable simply by using `ansible_default_ipv4`, you will get the address via:

- `ansible_default_ipv4.address` or
- `ansible_default_ipv4['address']`.

Both variants are the same in this case.

So you can use this as a basis for the split of the dots.

Splitting is possible with the filter `split()`, so you can do the splitting with the following code:
`ansible_default_ipv4.address | split('.')`

You can then address the 4th element with either `.3` or the equivalent `[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this for all hosts in the play in one go, you can extract the ip fact from each hosts, map the split function and retain only the fourth element for each result.

Some references to understand the playbook below:

- Check the `ansible_play_hosts` [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) definition
- See ansible documentation for [map('extract', ....)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables)
- See the global documentation for the [jinja2 `map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  vars:
    my_last_ips_digits: "{{ 
      ansible_play_hosts |
      map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) |
      map('split', '.') | map(attribute=3)
    }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Print last ip digits for all hosts
      debug:
        var: my_last_ips_digits
      run_once: true
```

Of course, you can reuse that list variable anywhere you like besides a debug output.